# Django return redirect() does nothing

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently try to redirect from one view to another view. However, nothing happens, the token gets printed and that's it.

```
class SocialLoginInvUserAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        print(request.data["token"])
        return redirect("auth_user_login")
```

Here is the login url:

```
     url(r'login/$',
      LoginInvUserAPIView.as_view(),
      name='auth_user_login'),
```

Comment: Why is it a static method?

Comment: Because I do not need access to the class' attributes or the the attributes of another instance of a class. I am not sure if this was a good thing to do, though

Comment: if you are worried about pylint I think you could add this extenstion https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django